# Can I still play Starcraft 1 on Battle.Net?

Tags: battle.net, starcraft

Can I still play Starcraft 1 multiplayer on Battle.Net?

Comment: You should be playing SC2 ;-)

Comment: @Ivo I bought SC1 so I *wouldn't* buy SC2, yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can. You still have to have a valid SC1 account though. And it uses Classic Battle.Net, so you can't hook up with RealID friends from SC2 and WoW.

Answer (score 7):

[Blizzard has released Starcraft 1 for free](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/04/19/original-starcraft-and-brood-war-are-now-free). If you download that version (you'll probably need to login into your blizzard account in order to do so), you'll be allowed to login into battle net without any problems.

Comment: plus it now has it's launcher in the Bnet client

Comment: Plus for a few dollars there is a remastered version (16:9 resolution with improved graphics)

Comment: @kosmos yes, and easier to see burrowed lurkers! Talk about pay to win! /s

Comment: I didn't play since 2000s so I don't remember if burrowed lurkers was harder to see compared with this graphic remastered version. I've payed ~9€ for the remastered version so almost everybody can play with better graphics (that was the point of the comment). I can't talk about "Pay to win" because I'm basically new to the game and, as far as I remember, everything seems equal. But the timer! Remastered version has a game timer that (I think) standard hasn't. Though it's an advantage only if you don't have a clock. Do you know more advantages between remastered and standard?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 9x or Windows XP, perhaps. I haven't been able to play Starcraft 1 for years, simply because I upgraded to Vista (then Win 7) as soon as it came out, and Starcraft 1's DirectDraw suffers massive miscolorization on the newer OS's. The only way I can play is within a tiny window of a virtual machine which I can't handle because my screen resolution is too high so the window is like 3 inches by 3 inches (no I couldn't get it to stretch with the VM software I was trying).

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Starcraft runs fine on my Win7 machine.  It's a bit grainy perhaps but the colors are right.  Have you tried the XP Virtual Machine in Win7?  Actually, ask a question here about this, people might be able to get you running.

Comment: XP Mode (VM) didn't work. Also tried VMWare Player and Oracle VirtualBox. Some of these run the game but none of these stretch to fill the screen. I have a 28-inch monitor @ 1920x1200. Bleh.

Comment: It work fine on my Win7 -- just need to open Personalize->Display Settings dialogs (from the desktop's right-click menu) before launching the game.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-i-get-an-older-windows-95-98-game-to-run-in-windows-7-64-bit-without-some

Comment: I play SC1 on lans under Ubuntu, via Wine.

Comment: @paxinum I play on ubuntu as well and am able to use battle.net. I just needed to disable the "Allow the window manager to control the windows" option under the graphics tab on wine config so Battle.net could update. That and I had to port forward the usual port 6112. Also using wine .9.14. The game slows down severely for versions after that. On a side note, when I first got my laptop 6 years ago, I was able to run starcraft fine on vista. So far I've run it on Windows ME, Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Ubuntu via wine.

Comment: The problem seems to be explorer, killing that before launching the game works for me. See my full writeup on how to get worms Armageddon running with the correct colours (which has the same problem) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/how-can-i-play-worms-armageddon-on-windows-7/110332#110332