# Empire Earth Window 10 Issues

Tags: windows-10, empire-earth

I have Empire Earth from GOG.

If I am playing the game, sometimes (often) the game window disappears and I can see my desktop and in about 1-2 seconds, the game comes "back," but the UI is blinking. I need to open for example the tech tree, close it, and then the game is ok. It is frustrating.

Can anybody help with this? I am running on Windows 10.

Comment: While not _exactly_ the same thing, maybe try some of the things listed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69346/163757) in the top voted answer.  You may also want to checkout [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6762/163757) as well.